# Laravel query builder - Migrating from traditional SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm slowly starting to migrate my website to `Laravel` and I', finding it very challenging to say the least. I now have to rewrite all my traditional `sql` statements and the documentation doesn't give simple snippets of common `sql` queries. Below is my login script that I've spent hours trying to figure out how to convert..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row['verified'] == 1) {
        echo "Valid";
    } elseif ($row['verified'] == 0) {
        echo "not aValid";
    }
} elseif ($count == 0) {
    echo "not Valid";
}
```

Any help or guidance will greatly be appreciated. I need to be pointed in the right direction as to how to do simple queries like this one as my site is riddled with a lot of them. I'm starting to think I may have written my logic in a bad way to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting your query can be done pretty easily thanks to Laravel's [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries):

```php
$user = DB::table('users')->where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])->first();

if (!is_null($user)) {
    if ($user->verified) {
        echo 'Valid';
    } else {
        echo 'Not Valid';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Not Valid';
}
```

Building queries using the query builder is actually a pretty simple process if you're queries are not extremely complex. You should read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) in depth and you should be fine. Also, when your queries don't seem to return the results you're expecting you can always use the `toSql` method that returns a string containing the SQL query that was being generated, so this:

```php
dump(DB::table('users')->where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])->toSql());
```

Will print this:

```
select * from `users` where (`email` = ? and `password` = ?)
```

The question marks are placeholders for the actual values being used in conditions, because Laravel uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with bindings to build the queries, meaning you don't need to escape your values when passing them to the builder, so no worries about [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

---

That being said, it looks to me like you're trying to authenticate a user with that query. If that's the case, I strongly suggest you use the [Authentication System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) that is part of Laravel.

Comment: Thanks very much... I'll give this a try now. In my controller I put `Use 'DB'` is this all I have to do to be able to run queries?

Comment: Yes that is enough. `DB` is a [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades) that offers quick access to the Query Builder.

Comment: My `IDE` is giving error `undefined class DB` and also getting `Error 500` if I submit the form

Comment: If you have the `use DB;` statement in the file where you actually build the query then it must work. The IDE is probably complaining about the class because it's an alias defined in `config/app.php` and it cannot be resolved via traditional methods. You can use the [Laravel IDE Helper](http://bit.ly/1knNqZc) to stop the IDE from complaining, but that's not an actual error. About the HTTP 500 error, you should make sure that `APP_DEBUG` is set to `true` in your `.env` file, so errors are displayed in the browser, or check the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file to see what the error is.

Comment: Just to confirm I can then access column values like this correct? `$firstname = $user->firstName` to get the firstName of the user

Comment: Yes, each column of the table can be accessed as an object property, so if the column name is `firstName` then you can access it using `$user->firstName`.

Comment: Also from your code it means there's no need to use `count()` if my aim is to check check if the query produced a row correct?

Comment: Yes, because the `first` method returns the entry details or `null`. That's why if the result is not `null`, then it means an entry was found.